# Revert changes done to Facebook chat

Tags: facebook, chat, facebook-messenger

I'm new to Facebook (yes, that is still possible!). Yesterday, when I registered, Facebook chat in my account was tiny (about  1/5 of screen height) and showed only true on-line Friends.

Today, though I'm pretty sure I didn't change anything, I have Facebook chat as large sidebar, stick to right margin of browser, it is as high as my browser window, and shows all (most) of my Friends, not only those, who are on-line (others showed with time of last activity).

What did I switched or which Facebook option controls this? Can I revert to "old" (yesterday) tiny little chat box? I don't see anything in Chat's settings (knob  icon) or in my account's general settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on your browser size. Beyond a certain width, the chat window merges with the Facebook ticker. You can probably get your browser real estate by closing that window.

[image: Turn off sidebar with cogwheel]

Comment: All, right! After some tests -- totally agree with you on browser's windows sizes and integration. But what I did, that chat changed from showing only on-line friends (which I mostly prefer) to showing all of them (most of them) and only marking those on-line with a red dot. Is this something, I can customize?